# How do I enable session support in Google App Engine (Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, cookies, session-state

How do I enable GAE session support using Java?

Also, a related question: I only want to store a small amount of state in sessions (basically, just a key) -- will GAE store this information in a client-side cookie, and if so, how secure is that approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Sessions are stored using a randomly generated (meaningless) ID on the client side, and datastore & memcache on the server side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the first question. In your `appengine-web.xml` have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ...
  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this Link provided by in comments in appengine-web.xml:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions